# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getRowData(String rowKey) must be implemented when basic rowKey algorithm is not used

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have upgraded PrimeFaces from 5.1 final to 5.2 final (the Community Release). I have a `<p:dataTable>` which is lazily loaded as follows (a minimal example to reproduce the problem for a pure testing purpose only).

```
<p:dataTable  var="row"
              value="#{testManagedBean}"
              lazy="true"
              editable="true"
              rowKey="#{row.fruitId}"
              selection="#{testManagedBean.selectedValues}"
              rows="50">

    <p:column selectionMode="multiple"/>

    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{testManagedBean.onRowEdit}"/>

    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{row.fruitId}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Fruit Name">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{row.fruitName}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="#{row.fruitName}"/>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Price">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{row.price}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="#{row.price}"/>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Edit">
        <p:rowEditor/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

The corresponding managed bean :

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestManagedBean extends LazyDataModel<Fruit>  implements Serializable {

    private List<Fruit> selectedValues; // Getter & setter.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TestManagedBean() {}

    private List<Fruit> init() {
        List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<Fruit>();

        Fruit fruit = new Fruit();
        fruit.setFruitId(1);
        fruit.setFruitName("Mango");
        fruit.setPrice(500D);
        fruits.add(fruit);

        fruit = new Fruit();
        fruit.setFruitId(2);
        fruit.setFruitName("Guava");
        fruit.setPrice(300D);
        fruits.add(fruit);

        fruit = new Fruit();
        fruit.setFruitId(3);
        fruit.setFruitName("Apple");
        fruit.setPrice(600D);
        fruits.add(fruit);
        return fruits;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Fruit> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
        List<Fruit> fruits = init();
        setRowCount(fruits.size());
        return fruits;
    }

    public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
        System.out.println("id : "+((Fruit)event.getObject()).getFruitId());
    }
}
```

While editing the `onRowEdit()` method is supposed to be invoked which is bound to,

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{testManagedBean.onRowEdit}"/>
```

When a row is in an edit mode and the update link marked by a tick is clicked, it causes the following exception to be thrown.

```
Info:   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getRowData(String rowKey) must be implemented when basic rowKey algorithm is not used.
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getRowData(String rowKey) must be implemented when basic rowKey algorithm is not used.
    at org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel.getRowData(LazyDataModel.java:95)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getRowData(DataTable.java:1214)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decodeMultipleSelection(SelectionFeature.java:90)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decode(SelectionFeature.java:48)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:62)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:834)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:281)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:573)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:821)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1690)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:380)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1690)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1690)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:266)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:930)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Warning:   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getRowData(String rowKey) must be implemented when basic rowKey algorithm is not used.
javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getRowData(String rowKey) must be implemented when basic rowKey algorithm is not used.
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:273)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:930)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getRowData(String rowKey) must be implemented when basic rowKey algorithm is not used.
    at org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel.getRowData(LazyDataModel.java:95)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getRowData(DataTable.java:1214)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decodeMultipleSelection(SelectionFeature.java:90)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decode(SelectionFeature.java:48)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:62)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:834)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:281)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:573)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:821)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1690)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:380)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1690)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1690)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:266)
    ... 34 more

Severe:   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getRowData(String rowKey) must be implemented when basic rowKey algorithm is not used.
    at org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel.getRowData(LazyDataModel.java:95)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getRowData(DataTable.java:1214)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decodeMultipleSelection(SelectionFeature.java:90)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decode(SelectionFeature.java:48)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:62)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:834)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:281)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:573)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:821)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1690)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:380)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1690)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1690)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:266)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:930)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This should not happen because `rowKey="#{row.fruitId}"` is used with the given `<p:dataTable>`.

The exception disappears only when the `rowKey` attribute is removed and the `getRowKey()` and the `getRowData()` methods are implemented in the associated managed bean as follows.

```
@Override
public Object getRowKey(Fruit fruit) {
    return fruit != null ? fruit.getFruitId() : null;
}

@Override
public Fruit getRowData(String rowKey) {
    List<Fruit> fruits = (List<Fruit>) getWrappedData();
    Integer value = Integer.valueOf(rowKey);

    for (Fruit fruit : fruits) {
        if (fruit.getFruitId().equals(value)) {
            return fruit;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Is it mandatory in the newest version of PrimeFaces (5.2 final) which was not needed in the previous version of PrimeFaces (5.1 final)?

<sub>Tested on Mojarra 2.3.0-m02. I presumed that there should not be any relevance with this version of Mojarra.</sub>

Comment: This will probably get removed as not being formulated correctly or even rude etc, but did you use any kind of search functionality and took a look at the PrimeFaces forum. Discussed several times there the last weeks. Someone else may collect the reputation for formulating a correct answer. Edit:Sorry Tiny, only now see it is 'you', still my comment holds value. See http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=41556

Comment: Just had a look as @Kukeltje says and found: `we changed that part by design cause the rowKey attribute handling with a LazyDataModel is not correct.`. I think it makes full sense, you can't trust that id for being fully initialized in a lazy data model. However, you can rely in an action listener which will load it from your controller when it's requested. Here it is the thread: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=41556

Comment: This time, I am too late to upgrade PrimeFaces and could not use its released candidates, since my application is heavily dependent upon PrimeFaces Extensions whose final version has been released just a few  hours ago from now. This requires adjusting the code at several places now.

Comment: @Kukeltje : Would you like answering this question? You may just quote from the PrimeFaces Community Forum which I am going to do otherwise. It does not make much sense to delete the question itself. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, but you may do it to. It's not always about the reputation points ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in [this](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=41556#p130851) link pointing to the PrimeFaces Community Forum,

> We changed that part by design cause the `rowKey` attribute handling
>   with a `LazyDataModel` is not correct.

Those two methods `getRowKey()` and `getRowData()` need to be implemented in the associated managed bean whenever `LazyDataModel<T>` is used as shown in the question.

From [PrimeFaces User Guide (PDF)](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html) -  (5.1 (page 164) and 5.2 (page 166)) :

> Lazy Loading is an approach to deal with huge datasets efficiently,
>   regular ajax based pagination works by rendering only a particular
>   page but still requires all data to be loaded into memory. Lazy
>   loading datatable renders a particular page similarly but also only
>   loads the page data into memory not  the whole dataset. In order to
>   implement this, you’d  need  to bind a
>   `org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel` as the value and implement load
>   method  and  enable lazy option. **Also it is required to implement
>   `getRowData` and `getRowKey` if you have selection enabled.**

---

The attribute `rowKey` may be used, when `lazy` is disabled -- is set to `false` (default) and row selection is enabled.

From [PrimeFaces User Guide (PDF)](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html) -  (5.1 (page 159) and 5.2 (page 161)) :

> RowKey should a unique identifier from your data model and used by
>   datatable to find the selected rows. You can either define this key by
>   using the `rowKey` attribute or by binding a data model which
>   implements `org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel`.

Such as,

```
<p:dataTable var="car"
             value="#{carBean.cars}"
             selection="#{carBean.selectedCars}"
             rowKey="#{car.id}">

    <p:column selectionMode="multiple"/>
    <!--columns-->
</p:dataTable>
```